# Facebook post id returned using graph api and the posted Id on facebook are not same

Tags: facebook, comments

I need to retrive the comments for the particular post on Facebook, so whenever i post sometext on facebook using graph api as mentioned below.

$result = $facebook->api($fid.'/feed/','post',$attachment);

It returns the post id in response($result).

When i login to facebook and hover on the "datetime" for that post, it shows me the different post id and not the returned one in my response, so i couldn't get the comments for that post id.

I use to get the comments using the code below.

$post_comments = $facebook->api('/'.$postid,array('access_token' =>'AAAAxxxxxx'));

Any Help would be Appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The Post ID returned by the API is in the form `{user_id}_{post_id}` so its slightly different than the one facebook shows. However, if you replace the `_` with `/posts/` you get the same URL as the one Facebook provides.

Comment: Hi Niraj, Thanks for your reply..i used to save the post id in that format({user_id}_{post_id}) what you have mentioned, and i use to fetch comments with that id, but i notice that the post id in my response is of the form {user_id}_{xxxxx}, and the post id in the facebook is of the form {user_id}_{yyyyy}.so both seems to be different some times, so i cant fetch the comments for that post

Comment: One way to double check the link. Go to your 'Activity Log' in facebook and see if the links are still the same / different. Sometimes, the timeline gets the links wrong...(possible bug).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this behaviour myself some days ago – user used three different apps and thereby created three individual link-posts. The "x minutes ago"-link for each of them showed a different number of minutes, but clicking on any of them led to the same post, the first on that was made.

I suspect it has something to do with all three post being made from page tabs on the same fan page(?) – but i looks like a bug to me, because to any of his friends following the "x minutes ago"-link on one of the other two posts it surely must be a bit confusing to be taken to a different post detail page than the one the actually clicked on.